# I want to load script after loading specific data from JSON in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mathjax

I want to load Script tag after data.post.content is loaded inside HTML.

Basically, I want to run the MathJax.js script inside HTML.

My code:

```
return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.post.title}</h1>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.post.content }}></p>
      <Script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.hostmath.com/Math/MathJax.js?config=OK" strategy="afterInteractive"/>
    </div>
  );
```

My Script is working if I reload the page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're populating `Script` with client-side rendering (server-side rendering is good because data is loaded already on the server).

You can try this way to fix (below snippet), but with this way, you need to set `data.post.content` in states for UI re-rendering

```js
return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.post.title}</h1>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.post.content }}></p>
      {data.post.content && <Script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.hostmath.com/Math/MathJax.js?config=OK" strategy="afterInteractive"/>}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem.
Is there an way to reload <p>...</p> after loading script.
For ex. by using <Script type=...   src=...   onLoad={ () => {} } />

Comment: You can try this way. Firstly, we need to have a function `const setInnerHTML = () => ({__html: data.post.content })` and then you call that function like this `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={setInnerHTML()}></p>`. We're doing this because the function will be re-rendered every time once that component gets called.

Comment: This works only when clicking on the same page that I clicked last time. I think this is due to cached data. For other pages, I have to refresh the page to use the script.
I observed that the script is loading perfectly but not executing on `data.post.content` component.

Comment: You need to add a state for `data.post.title` and observe it with `useEffect` or `componentDidUpdate`, whenever the data, as well as state, get updated, UI will be re-rendered accordingly.